# IIS 7.5 FTP with ftps (SSL)

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-7.5, tls

I have an FTP server that uses IIS 7.5, running on a Windows Server 2008 machine. When I try to connect to this server using filezilla with implicit TLS (ftps://), I always recieve this error:

```
GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

The server connects fine when I don't use TLS (ftp://) or with explicit TLS (ftpes://) so I believe it is not a SSL issue.

Am I missing a configuration here?

Update:
I was trying to connect to ftps using port 2122.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you have a binding for port 990, as that is the implicit FTPS port.  Without that binding your site in IIS will not support implicit FTPS.

Comment: By binding, do you mean to open port 990 in firewalls?

Comment: @SyakurRahman No, I mean a binding on the FTP site in IIS.  Sites (web or FTP) in IIS operate based on bindings, a combination of IP, port, protocol, and sometimes host header name that define which sites answer to which requests.

Comment: @SyakurRahman Here's an example of a port 21 binding:  http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gByQR4TlBfw/UGs3h7yRuaI/AAAAAAAAMNY/8ZdpmjmK2bQ/s1600/IIS.PNG

Comment: Okay, it did worked :). The previous test I did was using a custom port which is 2122. I already have a binding to that port, is there something else I need to configure so I could use port 2122 with ftps?

Comment: You can use port 2122 with explicit FTPS assuming you connect to that port on your client.  Implicit FTPS can only be used with port 990.